# dynamically load-balanced task queue

Tags: load-balancing, message-queue, task-queue, gearman

**Set up**
Front-end machine receives web requests and puts 3 different kinds of tasks into `Gearman` server.
3 worker machines registered with that gearman server, each can perform any of those tasks.

**Different tasks consume different resources.**
Each task is different in terms of cpu/ram/io consumption.
The amount of tasks in queue is much greater then the number of workers, meaning each working machine registered multiple worker instances with gearman.

**How to dynamically load balance it**
The problem is that one worker machine can get all the cpu extensive tasks, another one would get the i/o extensive task, while ideally a worker can perform much better doing all this different kind of task in parallel.

Perhaps gearman isn't the right tool here?

Comment: I know rabbitmq has 'fair' balancing, where the next task goes to the machine that indicated it's free. But a machine can execute 3 tasks in parallel, each consuming different kind of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you could use RabbitMQ that has [fair dispatching](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) and
use 3 different queues,
one for the cpu consuming task, one for the i/o and one for the network.

Thus every time a worker machine finishes any of this tasks, it would aknowledge it's done with it and get another task of the same resource-consuming type.